# Will Vixie Cron execute a command if the user is not logged in?

Tags: unix, cron, freebsd

If a user adds an entry to crontab, will the command be executed even if they are not logged in?

Comment: Scheduled, unattended jobs are one of the major purposes for `cron`, regardless of which implementation - so, yes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Scheduled, unattended jobs are one of the major purposes for cron, regardless of which implementation - so, yes... – twalberg

Answer received from twalberg.